# Why is $1 in a function not printing the script's first argument?

Tags: bash, shell-script, function

Why doesn't `echo $1` print `$1` in this simple bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash
# function.sh
print_something () {
echo $1
}
print_something

$ ./function.sh 123  -> why doesn't it print '123' as a result?
```

Comment: because you forgot the $1 when calling print_something. Please try to include text in the question and not in the title.

Comment: thanks. What should be the echo argument if I need to insert in the script the commands: print_something "$1"; print_something "$2"; and maybe more?

Comment: When I saw this in HNQ I thought you were printing dollar-bills and hoped to read some juicy story about how your printer detects that you're printing fake money.

Comment: @pipe I've had that happen to me before, for some reason it refuses to print anything not just the ones with the anti-printing preventions.

Answer (score 43):

Positional parameters refer to the script's arguments in the main level of the script, but to *function arguments* in function body. So

```
print_something Something
```

would actually print `Something`.

If you want to pass the script's arguments to a function, you must do that explicitly. Use

```
print_something "$1"
```

to pass the first argument, or

```
print_something "$@"
```

to pass all of them, though the function in example only uses the first one.

Comment: Passing `"$@"` to `print_something`, as it's currently written, would still only print the first of the arguments though.

Comment: But the point was to show how to *pass* all arguments, I presume. The fact that the function, as it stands, only uses the first of its arguments is a bit irrelevant.

Comment: Well, just thinking there's no point in passing all the arguments along if only the first one is being used.

Comment: @Kusalananda ``"$@"`` has quotes, making it a single argument to ``print_something``.

Comment: @allo No. `"$*"` would be a single string (joined on the first character of `$IFS`) while `"$@"` would be a list of individually quoted elements.

Comment: @Kusalananda the point of telling someone who wants to pass the command-line parameters to a function to use `"$@"`, even if _in this case_ there is only one such parameter, is to cover _all_ such cases.  If the OP decides to add a second parameter, there's nothing to change in the function invocation.  And everyone else who reads this will learn the right way to do it to avoid having to re-do it later, too.

Comment: I think you are saying the opposite while meaning the correct. The positional arguments are those passed to that function, not that in the global scope of the whole script. For that reason `print_something` cannot see the `$1` of the script, as it is not passed to the function.

Comment: «The positional arguments are those passed to that function, not that in the global scope» — They are both positional (`$N`), but they do refer to different data, depending on the scope

Answer (score 11):

This is because a called function gets its own set of positional parameters, independent  of the parent's / caller's set.
Try

```
print_something "$1"
```

(and `echo "$1"`, or even better `printf '%s\n' "$1"`, remember to quote parameter expansions and that `echo` can't be used for arbitrary data).

Comment: You need to become clearer what you are talking about. The caller's `$1` is generally different from the function's `$1`, although they CAN become the same if used like proposed above. If I get you right, the `echo` can stay the same (`echo $1`) when the function is called with single parameters (`print_something $2` takes the caller's $1 and "makes" it `$1` inside the function)

Comment: Using `echo $1` doesn't make sense unless you want `$1` to be treated as a $IFS-delimited list of file patterns to expand. `echo "$1"` would make more sense, though would not output the content of `$1` for values of `$1` like `-nene`, `-EE`...